# How to build a mix-in architecture framework in C#?

Tags: c#, frameworks, mixins

I have a concept for a framework of controls that I would like to build.  What makes this idea different is that I do not intend to take the "one size fits all" approach or the "one control to rule them all" approach.

As an example, Telerik makes a very nice Grid control, as does ComponentOne, Xceed, etc.. However, they are all gigantic controls with hundreds or thousands of methods and properties, complex object model hiearchies, etc...  All too often these grids are way overkill for what you need, but you still have to take on the herculean task of learning the entire grid to do something simple.

My concept is more of an "mix-in" aproach.  Where you create a very simple control, and then build features that you can "add-in" to the control a la carte.  For example, you have a simple grid, and you want to add grid "sections" with headers and footers for each.

Ok, so where's the problem?  The traditional way of doing something like this is via multiple inheritance, which C# does not support. Even if it did support it, I'm still of the opinion that MI adds more problems than it solves.

So I'm soliciting SO for opinions on how to approach this problem.  Would MEF be a potential solution?

EDIT:

Something that occurs to me is that it could be possible to use expression trees to build the control from various expressions.  I'd have to think through this some more, but it's an interesting concept.

Another possible option might be a "Control Generator" that generates an assembly based on a the selected features.  That seems more complex, but with T4 might be managable.

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb625996.aspx

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I've already largely rejected extension methods because they can't really provide additional state, only methods.  The technique you reference would require the implementation of all additional state by the end user which I'm not really keen on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options

1. Consider the Decorator pattern; small objects that extend behavior of a fairly minimalist class that you can build up at runtime. The canonical example in the Dotnet framework would be around the IO streams (e.g. StreamReader/Writer, TextStreamReader/Writer, FileStreamReader/Writer); it's fairly common also in OO UI frameworks, with the typical example looking something like `var window=new HorizontalScrollingWindowDecorator(new VerticalScrollingWindowDecorator(new Window));`
2. The State, Strategy, Command, and Composite patterns offer various alternatives for dealing with composition of behavior without requiring lots of control flow. For example, you delegate certain types of behavior to the current State of your object (some of your class methods basically call methods of the current object State). You can also delegate behavior to command objects, or build up complex commands using composite commands. Single inheritance generally leads you to favor composition of objects over inheritance, and these are all classic patterns for composing behavior that work well with single-inheritance.
3. You can use delegates for the "hole in the middle" pattern that's commonplace in functional programming, when some small piece of behavior needs to be implemented by a particular instance.
4. You can use PostSharp or a similar aspect-oriented programming tool to do runtime or compile-time weaving of behavior, especially useful for cases when behavior needed by several different classes that doesn't have much to do with the primary responsibility of that class.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think multiple inheritance would be a bad way to implement this kind of design anyway. It seems that multiple inheritance is a bad design most of the time.  Inheritance is far to rigid a relationship between components.

Composition is far more flexible, in which case MEF would be a very good starting point for this.

The base class for your controls would be a container of behaviours - essentially a MEF container.

It still leaves the question of how other classes interact with your controls.  There are many options. For example standard interfaces on the base control, messaging, or even using dynamic binding in C# 4.0.

Comment: I agree on the MI.  I merely mentioned that this was the "traditional" way of dealing with the problem.  Perhaps I should investigate MEF more.  I was hoping someone with more experience would comment on whether that line of analysis would be beneficial or not.

Comment: I've used MEF quite lightly in a web application.  From what I've seen of it I'd say it is very well designed,  and allows for very flexible linking of components.  However you have to think through how your going to combine the plugin/swapable nature of MEF with the markup for your controls.  You'll need something to parse the markup - and this code might have to know so much about the controls it's parsing markup for that might negate the need for MEF anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to try to answer without commenting on whether it's a problem that's worth solving.

I haven't tried this for a component, but in theory there's the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern): you could add plug-ins at run-time to intercept the control's (keyboard and mouse) input and (screen) output.

Comment: I thought about that, but if you are using attributes to implement the decoration, it can get pretty ugly pretty fast, and I think the required reflection would incur a significant performance penalty.

Comment: Right.. this was my thought on MEF.  However, I don't know MEF enough to know whether this sort of this is practical.  Or if I would have to develop my own code injection method.

Answer (score 1):

WPF addresses this by allowing you to composite visual representations of logical elements with data templates.  Rather than mixing in features to create a new Control class, the Control class itself provides extensibility points through the ability to incorporate Content of varied types, with a rich templating system to arrange and visualize the Content.

In other words, there is still arguably 'one control to rule them all', but the control is a skeleton rather than a fully-fleshed body.  The scaffolding provides a comprehensible framework within which to add features and the templating system provides the glue for fleshing out the control's parts.

---

Regarding MEF, what MEF buys you is discovery and injection of extension code.  It's valuable, but doesn't directly address the problem you've described.  Your problem has less to do with discovery of code and more to do with the mechanism of how that code is composited to create a coherent overall Control.  MEF can be helpful to perform some of the gluing, but it's a relatively small part of the problem.

Comment: That's good insight on MEF.  Thanks, was hoping for a comment like this to help me narrow down the viable avenues of analysis.

Comment: @Mystere Man, if you haven't played with WPF at all, I recommend taking a look at it.  Even if you don't plan to use it, the designers of the framework have incorporated a lot of very good ideas and have clearly put a great deal of thought into how to create an extremely extensible UI without requiring a bunch of custom control code.  If you play with it, do yourself a favor and focus on looking at the XAML rather than using the VS designer.  XAML is an extremely powerful language for the concise description of objects and their relationships, directly relating to your problem of composition.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to build an Add-In type of framework then? I would definitely point you toward Managed Extensibility Framework. Can be used in .Net 4.0 with WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a framework that already has implemented mixins for a reference, have a look on the re-motion framework (https://www.re-motion.org/). It is amazing how easy mixins can implemented in this framework,

The following is a reference application at a "Hello World" level.

With the assemblies downloaded from the webseite, create a class library and a console app in VS2010, in both projects add references to the assmblies remotion.dll and remotion.interfaces.dll.

```
using System;

namespace Domain
{
  public class Person
  {
    public Person()
    {
    }
    public Person(Person person)
    {
      FirstName = person.FirstName;
      LastName = person.LastName;
      BirthDay = person.BirthDay;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
  }
}



using System;
using Remotion.Mixins;

namespace Domain
{
  public interface IEmployeeMixin
  {
    int Salary { get; set; }
    DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
  }

  [Extends(typeof(Person))]
  public class EmployeeMixin : IEmployeeMixin
  {
    public int Salary { get; set;  }
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set;}
    public EmployeeMixin()
    {
      // set default values
      Salary = 1000;
      HireDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
  }
}



using Domain;
using Remotion.Reflection;
using Remotion.Mixins;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Person p = new Person();
      p.FirstName = "John";
      p.LastName = "Doe";

      var employee = (IEmployeeMixin)ObjectFactory.Create<Person>(ParamList.Create(p));

      System.Console.WriteLine("Fullname: {0}", ((Person)employee).FirstName + " " + ((Person)employee).LastName);
      System.Console.WriteLine("Salary: {0}", employee.Salary);

      System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Based on this reference implementation, it should be easy to get an idea, how this mixins are implemented in this framework. If you want to get more information about this framework (it is a complete DDD development framework) or the mixins, do not hesitate to ask. I can provide you with more documentation.

Stefan